# Screenshot of a single window comes up blank

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen-capture

I followed the instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

> How to take a screenshot of a window Press Shift-Command-4. The
>   pointer changes to a crosshair. Press the Space bar. The pointer
>   changes to a camera. Move the camera over a window to highlight it.
>   Click your mouse or trackpad. To cancel, press the Esc (Escape) key
>   before you click. Find the screenshot as a .png file on your desktop.

But afterwards, I get a blank image (transparent everywhere). [image]

Has anyone seen this issue, and if so, what am I doing wrong? I am on Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Does this happen on a specific app or does it happen on multiple apps?

Comment: Version of macOS?  Application you're attempting to take a screeenshot of?

Comment: OS version is: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (also in the last line of question);
Seems to happen to all my applications; I've tried this on: Chrome, Sublime Text, Adobe Acrobat

Comment: This happens only for the "Spacebar" version. If I just do Cmd+Shift+4 (no spacebar) it works fine.

Comment: what is spacebar version?

Comment: i figured out space bar version, it works fine on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when a window has contents that are rendered outside the windowserver. Mostly 2d/3d, video and modelling software might do this. Some applications do it on purpose, like the Apple DVD player.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the application "Grab" to take a picture of the screen, window, or selection. Grab comes with all Macs and is located in your "Utilities" folder. The Utilities folder is in with your applications.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out out what's causing it:

I'm using the Honer app https://github.com/puffnfresh/Honer.app, and it interferes with the screenshots, apparently. I've raised an issue about it on GitHub.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to render the contents off-screen and replace it post-processed later on after it put an overlay in place (which is what you see in the screen shot).

Answer (score 1):

Brightness Slider is also causing this bad behavior.

The solution is to quit it to recover the single window capture capability of Screen Capture.

[Brightness Slider](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/brightness-slider/id456624497)

[image: Whole screen grey image produced while trying to capture a single window with CMD-Shift-4, spacebar, with Brightness Slider open.]

Comment: Thank you - This was the exact fix in my case.  More specifically, if I adjusted the brightness to 100% w/o quitting then screenshots started to work once more.